# OCaml: creating a record from a function

Tags: ocaml

```
type node = {
  lan: string;
  lat: string;
};;

let rec read_nodes_from_list list = match list with
  | Xml.Element("node", _, _)::list' -> {lan="A"; lat="B"}::read_nodes_from_list list'
;;
```

I tried this to create a node record but it doesn't work. And suppose I have another type that has same attributes of node, how can I tell ocaml which type object to create?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Obviously, your function didn't work because you forgot to match with empty list:

```
let rec read_nodes_from_list list = match list with
  | Xml.Element("node", _, _)::list' -> {lan="A"; lat="B"}::read_nodes_from_list list'
  | [] -> []
```

What you're actually trying to do is a `map` operation on list, so your function could be written more elegantly as follows:

```
let read_nodes_from_list list =
   List.map (fun (Xml.Element("node", _, _)) -> {lan="A"; lat="B"}) list
```

However, the function may not work because pattern matching on `Xml.Element` is not exhaustive. You should be careful when handling remaining cases. For example, something like this would work:

```
let read_nodes_from_list list =
   List.map (function | (Xml.Element("node", _, _)) -> {lan="A"; lat="B"}
                      | _ -> {lan=""; lat=""}) list
```

To answer your question about record types, it considers a bad practice to have two record types with the same field label. You still can **put these record types in different submodules and distinguish them using module prefixes**. But as I said, having two similar record types in the same module causes confusion to you and the OCaml compiler.

Comment: Thank you! And what if I have two types with same attributes, how can I tell ocaml which type object to create?

Comment: They must be in different modules (sub or otherwise) and to avoid the aforementioned confusion not be opened. Each can be referenced with the normal module prefix syntax of `{ X.attr1 = ...; att2 = ...;}` for a given module `X`.